# django-redis and redis returning different results

Tags: redis, django-redis

I am using django-redis in my server to make less queries to the db. I recently setup a lambda where I needed to access the same data from the redis cache. But it seems that I am served different data if I connect to the redis cache using django-redis and if I use the python library redis.

The behaviour could be reproduced using the following code.
import redis
from redis.connection import HiredisParser
from redis.connection import ConnectionPool

```
connection_pool = ConnectionPool.from_url(url = 'redis://localhost:6379/1', parser_class=HiredisParser)

redis_client = redis.Redis(connection_pool=connection_pool)
redis_client.set('my_key', 'my_value')

# Access Redis data
redis_value = redis_client.get('my_key')
print(redis_value)
```

The response is `b'my_value`

```
from django_redis.cache import RedisCache

django_redis = RedisCache(server='redis://localhost:6379/1', params = {'OPTIONS': {'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient'}})
print(django_redis.get('my_key'))
```

The response is `None`

I also tried creating the connection without a pool but it also didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django redis adds a prefix to the keys when creating them. The prefix is supposed to be the version of the data stored. The default is version 1. So if you dont provide a version and your key is `my_key` then you key will be changed to `:1:my_key`